# css property for button

Tags: css

i have this html code, and this button, now i need to give different css to this two buttons.

Can you help me with that?

```
<div class="modal" style="display: none;">
<button type="button" class="action confirm">Konfirmo</button>
<button type="button" class="action cancel">Anullo</button>
</div>
```

It should be something like .modal .button .confirm 
I am trying to give different css to those two buttons. So , how can i do that!
Thanks..

Comment: i didn't understand you, so it would be somthing like: .modal button confirm{ } ?

Comment: You could declare this three (or more) classes separatley
`.modal {...}
.button {...}
.confirm {...}
.cancel {...}`
So you can combine then lately .. it makes your CSS reusable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
div.modal button.confirm{
    /* css for confirm buttom */
}

div.modal button.cancel{
    /* css for cancel buttom */
}
```

Comment: Thanks :)
it worked pretty good, i'm accepting the answer a little bit later!
Thanks

Comment: You probably don’t need `div` in the selector though.

Answer (score 2):

I’m not quite clear on what you’re asking, but are you looking for something like this?

```
.modal .confirm {
    color: green;
}

.modal .cancel {
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Style your first button with `.modal button.confirm { ... }` and the second with `.modal button.cancel { ... }`